# Open Side bar app launcher from any activity

Tags: android, user-interface

I am new to the Android Development. I am looking at creating a sample launcher application to replace android default launcher. I have created this launcher. But I am facing couple of problems:
 1. On click of Apps button I am showing all the apps installed on device. But app icons are of different size. I tried setting max height and width for them but still problem persists. 
 2. This launcher also includes side bar. If I am on home screen, I am able to slide from left to right to get this side bar. But when when I click on apps button, which starts new activity to show apps installed on device, now if I try to bring back side bar on this screen, it will not work. That means, side bar is tied to home screen. How to make this accessible from anywhere, from app list screen or from any other apps screen.

I guess these are common issues, but I couldn't find help on this on google. Can somebody please help?

Thanks,
Kailas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this problem.

1. App Icon Size

   - In xml where ImageView is defined, specify layout_width and layout_height as app_icon_size.

   ImageView
           android:id="@+id/item_app_icon"
           android:layout_width="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
           android:layout_height="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
2. Sidebar: I am not sure if it is a hack or right way to do this. I followed this approach: 
   I used window manager to host sidebar layout. And used window layout params to keep this window will always be on top any other application. Sidebar layout is nothing but a Drawing Layout to sliding it in and out comes with this layout by default.

   ```
   WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
   WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
          // Shrink the window to wrap the content rather than filling the screen
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           // Display it on top of other application windows, but only for the current user
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
           // Dont let it grab input focus
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
           // Make underlying application window visible through any transparent parts
           PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
   ); drawingLayout = (CustomDrawerLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sidebar, null);
   listView = (ListView) drawingLayout.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
   drawingLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.mipmap.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
   drawingLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
           super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
           WindowManager.LayoutParams newParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
           newParams.copyFrom(params);
           newParams.width = 150;
           windowManager.updateViewLayout(drawingLayout, newParams);
       }

           @Override
           public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
               super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
               windowManager.updateViewLayout(drawingLayout, params);
           }

       });

       loadApps(((View) drawingLayout).getContext());
       loadListView(((View) drawingLayout).getContext());
       addClickListener(((View) drawingLayout).getContext());
       windowManager.addView(drawingLayout, params);
   ```

This is working for me as expected. But still I am not sure about right solution to this. If you have any better approach, please let me know. Thanks!!