# How to create accessible from anywhere sidebar in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create sidebar in android like "RaySidebar" app. But I have no idea what should I use for this. I tried drawer navigation, but that just stays with home screen. When I enter any application this side bar is not accessible.

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities

Comment: I found solution for this: I have explained it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205301/open-side-bar-app-launcher-from-any-activity/29363367#29363367